# unknown property error struts2

Tags: java, jsp, struts2

I am developing a struts2 application. I have a property in my jsp file, which need to refer to a property of an object that is in a list, but I run into unknown property error,

**just to clarify:** 
lets say my jsp property is called x
my class is called a, it has a private String x and a set of getter and setters
a is in ArrayList called b, and b is in the action class that jsp file is referring to (it is referring to the correct class as it can find the properties that are action's member but not the x which is in class a).

Comment: This is not answerable unless you show us the JSP fragment and the relevant Java source code.

Comment: seems more like a maths question (assume x=1) rather than S2 question,provide some code and make sure you have tag lib in the class-path as well have defined it in your jsp

Comment: Help us to understand your problem to help you better?

Answer (score 0):

If I get your problem correctly (other people are right, it does read a bit like a Math problem) the problem is that Struts doesn't know to which element of the list to map the property in your JSP. Let me explain, suppose you have class A defined like this:

```
public class A {
    private String x;    
    //Getter and setter for x
}
```

and in your action class you have something like

```
public class MyAction extends ActionSupport {
    private A aProperty;
    //execute method and getter/setter for aProperty.
}
```

In this case you use aProperty.x to reference the x member of aProperty from your JSP. However, the moment your action class changes to

```
public class MyAction extends ActionSupport {
    private List<A> aList;
    //Execute method and getter/setter for aList.
}
```

you can no longer use aList.x since you need to tell Struts which item of the list to get in order to get/set x on this item. You can specify the item of the list you want to reference like this: aList[0].x

Let me know if this is not exactly what you were trying to ask in your question.